# Effect of high impedance Opamp buffer on current lost

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer, high-impedance

In the below figure, end-user have the choice to output 4-20mA or 0-10V (using MUX control by uC), I have inserted high impedance buffer(The part number is not correct) with the voltage divider to reduce 0-10v output to 0-5V so ADC can read it (can also reduce to 0-1V) and calibrate 0-10V.

I want to know if the user select 4-20mA as output,  the buffer will be ignored due to high impedance, is that correct. If not do I lose any current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOLFCM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What exactly do you mean by user output? Is this where the 4...20mA will be detected? There will be no significant current flowing into the input of the OpAmp. Depending on your measurement resolution and your specific OpAmp this will not even be detectable. The Input bias current (check the datasheet of you OpAmp) will be in the range of picoamp (FET input stage) to nanoamp (bipolar input stage).

Comment: User output: where the user can measure 4-20mA output. your comment basically answered my question.

Comment: It all depends on the user's input circuitry and the input circuits of the "high impedance circuit" (of which you say it isn't a TL081 device). Not much to go on really.

Comment: I see, in that case I will post it as a real answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no significant current flowing into the input of the OpAmp. Depending on your measurement resolution and your specific OpAmp this will not even be detectable.

The **Input bias current** (check the datasheet of your OpAmp) will be in the range of **picoamp** (FET input stage) to **nanoamp** (bipolar input stage).

**Example of impact:**
Assuming an input bias current of 10nA, this would be a fraction of the full scale input of \$ \frac{10~nA}{20~mA} = 0.5 \cdot 10^{-6} \$. This would require a resolution of \$ N = log_2 \frac{1}{0.5 \cdot 10^{-6}} = 21\$ Bit to change the result by only one single LSB.